# Query returns nothing

Tags: postgresql, java

I'm trying to get a car from my database using the value `FK_adId`. I've tried calling the method with the `FK_adId` value 52, and I've checked that a car with the `FK_adId` value 52 exists in my database. Why doesn't it get returned to me?

```
  public Car getCar(int adId) {
    Car car = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        if (con != null) {
            ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM \"car\" WHERE \"FK_adId\" = ?;");
            ps.setInt(1, adId);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            rs.next();
            if (rs.next()) {
                car = new Car(rs.getString("brand"), rs.getString("vin"), rs.getString("condition"), rs.getInt("distanceTraveled"), rs.getInt("age"), rs.getInt("price"), rs.getInt("FK_adId"));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
    return car;
}
```

Comment: Did you try executing the query SELECT * FROM car WHERE FK_adId = 52; directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
rs.next();
if (rs.next()) {
```

That code mean that you can try get SECOND row of the `ResultSet`, and since it looks like there's a single row with `FK_adId = 52`, you will have nothing in second time.